# How do you get the length of an array in sumologic?

Tags: arrays, sumologic

I am parsing json fields from my logs, in some of which I have arrays. Sumo seems to understand arrays fine, but I don't see a method of extracting the number of items in an array. (length, count, etc.)

`length` seems to be for character count only. But I'm adding a screenshot for demonstration of what I'm looking to do. In this case, `body` is an array of objects.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There was no documentation for that possibility as far as I could see.
However, since since they use JSONPath I have validated the following works:

```
| json "xyz.length()" as xyz_array_length
```